# Async Await Few Confusions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

As experiencing the new async & Await features of 4.5 I want to clear some confusions before going any further. I have been reading different article and also different question on SO and it help me undertands how Async and Await works. I will just try to put my understanding and confusions here and will appreciate if someone code educate me and other people who are looking for same things. I am discussing this in very simple wordings.

So Async is used so that compiler know that method marked by Async contains Await operation (Long operation). Latest framework contains different new builtin methods for Async Operations.

The builtin Async functions like connection.OpenAsync, ExecuteScalarAsync etc are used with Await keyword. I don't know the inner working of these Async Methods but my strong guess is that under the hood they are using Tasks.

Can I make this as general rule that Await will be with any method which implements Task. So if I need to create my own method which is performing long operation then will I create it as Task and when it is called I will use Await Keyword with it?

Second most important thing is that what is the rule of thumb of creating a method as Async or creating it as task. For example,

```
public void SampleMain()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
         DataTable dt = ReadData(int id);
    }
}

public DataTable ReadData(int id)
{ 
     DataTable resultDT = new DataTable();

     DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
     // Do Operation to Fill DataTable from first connection string
     adapter.Fill(dt1);

     DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
     // Do Operation to Fill DataTable from first connection string
     adapter.Fill(dt2); 

     // Code for combining datatable and returning the resulting datatable
     // Combine DataTables
     return resultDT;
}

public string GetPrimaryConnectionString()
{
     // Retrieve connection string from some file io operations
     return "some primary connection string";
}

public string GetSecondaryConnectionString()
{
     // Retrieve connection string from some file io operations
     return "some secondaryconnection string";
}
```

Now this is a very simple scenario that I have created based on some real world application I worked in past. So I was just wondering how to make this whole process Async.

Should I make GetPrimaryConnectionString and GetSecondaryConnectionString as Tasks and Await them in ReadData. Will ReadData be also a Task? How to call ReadData in the SampleMain function?

Another way could be to create a Task for ReadData in SampleMain and run that Task and skip converting other methods as Task. Is this the good approach? Will it be truly Asynchronous?

Comment: Sample of what do you mean "creating method as a task" would be more useful than somewhat random synchronous code you've added to the post.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Thanks for your response. I don't understand your comment completely. What I have presented is a sample raw scenario with as less code as possible to make the readers understand how to make this whole process as Asynchronous using Async and Await. It is not random at all.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary. Alright. So there is no need to change the methods GetPrimaryConnectionString and GetSecondaryConenctionString. If I just make the ReadData as Async will all this process be Asynchronous?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So Async is used so that compiler know that method marked by Async
>   contains Await operation

The `async` is used so that the compiler will have an indication to create a state-machine out of the method. An `async` method can have no `await`, and still work, though it will execute completely synchronously.

> The builtin Async functions like connection.OpenAsync,
>   ExecuteScalarAsync etc are used with Await keyword. I don't know the
>   inner working of these Async Methods but my strong guess is that under
>   the hood they are using Tasks.

`Task` is a promise of work to be completed in the future. There are a couple of ways to create a `Task`. But, `Task` isn't the only thing that can be represent an asynchronous operation. You can create an awaitable yourself if you wanted, all it needs it to implement a `GetAwaiter` method which returns a type implementing `INotifyCompletion`.

If you want to know how a method is implemented in the framework, [you can view the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DBCommand.cs,a32b4b2c68975bb5). In this particular case, they use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.

> Should I make GetPrimaryConnectionString and
>   GetSecondaryConnectionString as Tasks and Await them in ReadData. Will
>   ReadData be also a Task? How to call ReadData in the SampleMain
>   function?

There is nothing inherently asynchronous about retrieving a connection string. You usually (not always) use `async-await` with naturally async IO operations. In this particular case, the only actual async operation is `ReadData`, and if you want to make it asynchronous, you can use `SqlDataReader`, which exposes async methods.

An example, taken from the [ADO.NET teams blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/07/15/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta-part-2-examples.aspx):

```
public static async Task<Product> GetProductAndReviewsAsync(
            int productID, int reviewsToGet)

{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        const string commandString = GetProductByIdCommand + ";" 
                                    + GetProductReviewsPagedById;

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("productid", productID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("reviewStart", 0); 
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("reviewCount", reviewsToGet);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                if (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    Product product = GetProductFromReader(reader, productID);
                    if (await reader.NextResultAsync())
                    {
                        List<Review> allReviews = new List<Review>();
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())

                        {
                            Review review = GetReviewFromReader(reader);
                            allReviews.Add(review);
                        }
                        product.Reviews = allReviews.AsReadOnly();
                        return product;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(
                            "Query to server failed to return list of reviews");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For me the answer is now perfect with the edition of sample code. Thanks

Comment: In the sample code you have shared with me a explicit nullable object is mentioned inside task like Task<Product?>. Does this needs to be explicit?

Comment: @AdnanYaseen Any return type from an async operation needs to return a `Task` or a `Task<T>`. I removed the `Product?` to not confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

> how to make this whole process Async

If there are asynchronous versions of `adapter.Fill`, then simply `await` for it in `ReadData`, which in turn also become `async` and you can await for it in the caller method:

```
// in async button click event
button.Enabled = false;
var dt = await ReadData(int id);
button.Enabled = true;
... // do something with dt

public async Task<DataTable> ReadData(int id)
{ 
     ...
     var job1 = adapter.AsyncFill(dt1);
     var job2 = adapter.Fill(dt2); 
     // wait for all of them to finish
     Task.WaitAll(new[] {job1, job2});
     ...
     return Task.FromResult(resultDT); // dump approach
}
```

If there are no asynchronous version then **you** have to create them (by using `Task`):

```
// in async button click event
button.Enabled = false;
// run synchronous task asynchronously
var dt = await Task.Run(() => ReadData(int id));
button.Enabled = true;
... // do something with dt
```

`async/await` shines when it comes to UI, otherwise (if no UI is involved) just create task and run synchronous operation there.

Comment: `async-await` has nothing to do with UI. It *does help* to use it when you have non-blocking IO operations. But using `Task.Run` like that will not scale.

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks for providing me with sample code which helps me understand better. Just a quick question. You mentioned that if UI is not involved then I have to just create task and run synchronous. What If I have no UI involved and have to run Parallel tasks?

Comment: @AdnanYaseen, I don't think you will gain anything if you unfold that `for` into TPL. Bottleneck is either HDD or network. If you do some heavy processing (which is comparable to time needed to receive data), then it will surely helps. I myself never had to do such computations yet, therefore my answer is with regards to UI.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, do you mean creating **several tasks** and run then asynchronously, then of course `Task.AwaitAll` is better than waiting for each, or what do you mean as "will not scale"?

Comment: No. I mean that the power of async IO is the fact that it can scale, since you're not blocking any threads for the operation. What your example does is exactly the opposite, it blocks a thread waiting for IO.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I know it's not [*right way*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx), but sometimes it's unavoidable (there are no async methods to perform long operation) and putting it into `await Task.Run` way better than using other approaches in regards of UI: e.g `Task/Invoke`, `Thread/Invoke`, `Timer`, `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to use async-await is if your main thread might do something useful while another thread is doing the length operation. If the main thread would start the other thread and only wait for the other thread to finish, it is better to let the main thread do the action.

One of the things a main thread quite often does is keep the UI responsive.

You are right, under the hood async-await uses Task, hence you see that an async function returns a Task.

The rules:

- If a function would return void, the async version returns Task. If the function would return TResult, the async version should return Task`<TResult`>.
- There is one exception: the async event handler returns void.
- The return value of await Task is void. The return value of await Task`<TResult`> is TResult.
- Only async functions can call other async functions.
- If you have a non-async function you can still use the async function. However you cannot use await. Use the Task return value of the async function and the System.Threading.Tasks.Task methods to wait for the results.
- If you have an async function and want to start a non-async function in a separate thread, use:

  private int SlowCalculation(int a, int b)
  {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
      return a + b;
  }

  private async Task CalculateAsync(int a, int b)
  {
      Task myTask = Task.Run( () => SlowCalculation(a, b);
      // while SlowCalcuation is calculating slowly, do other useful things
      // after a while you need the answer
      int sum = await myTask;
      return sum;
  }

See that the return of await Task`<int`> is int.

Some people used to use functions like Task.ContinueWith. Because of the await statement that is not needed anymore. Await makes sure that the task is finished. The statement after the await is what you'd normally do in the ContinueWith.

In Task.ContinueWith you could say: "do this only if the task failed". The async-await equivalent for this is try-catch.

> Remember: if your thread has nothing useful to do (like keeping your UI responsive), don't use async-await

Starting several tasks in async-await and waiting for them to finish is done as follows:

```
private async Task MyAsyncFunction(...)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        tasks.Add(CalculateAsync(i, 2*i);
    }
    // while all ten tasks are slowly calculating do something useful
    // after a while you need the answer, await for all tasks to complete:
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    // the result is in Task.Result:
    if (task[3].Result < 5) {...}
}
```

> The async-await version of Task.Waitall is Task.WhenAll. WhenAll returns a Task instead of void, so you can await for it. The main thread remains responsive even while awaiting.

The main thread is not the case when using Task.WaitAll, because you don't await.